# Second Opinion on Tiling

Tags: bathroom, tile, tiling

We are having a bathroom tiled   but we're not quite happy with the result so far. The grout lines look uneven, the tile cuts aren't very clean and there's quite a lot of lippage and the walls are way off plumb.

I'm happy to give the trades person the benefit of the doubt for walls he hasn't prepared but two of them are his work from scratch.

Could someone please look at the pictures (*it's quite hard to capture these things on photos*) and give us a second opinion before we bring this up with the builder?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Full size pictures: https://photos.app.goo.gl/n42aAqbpmtZMaSU38

Comment: Stack Exchange hosts its own images.  Please edit your question and post the images inline rather than forcing users to go to an external password-protected page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You might want to [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know how this site works and get the best solutions.

Comment: @jwh20: Thanks for pointing that out. I tried opening the link in an anonymous window before posting, which worked fine. Nevertheless I added the pictures inline as well, hope it helps!

Comment: This is either a matter of opinion or a contractual issue. Both are off topic here. That's partly because we're a DIY site, and you're not D'ing it Y. That said, I'd not be happy with what I'm seeing.

Comment: This could possibly be OK for a DIYer who had never tiled anything before but certainly OK for a "professional".

Comment: @isherwood Thanks for the comment anyway. Based on the comments it might evolve into a DIY task very soon :D

Comment: If you're paying someone to do this work, I'd have him correct it before making the final payment.

Comment: To conclude the story, we brought it up with him and he failed to make things good so we refused to pay for the tiling (he didn't object) and we're getting someone else to essentially redo the entire lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be very shoddy workmanship. I can't tell a lot about how plumb the walls may or may not be but the wallboard has to be done properly in order to get good results once the tile is applied. However, it doesn't appear the tiler is very knowledgeable or skilled with properly installing tile. He/she should be using spacers between all of those tiles in order to control the gap between tiles. That's tiling 101.
It's always a good idea for jobs of this type to get referrals. Don't just accept the lowest bid.
IMO - I think the job needs to be redone.

Comment: Thanks HoneyDo. We did check the references and his previous work (pictures only because of covid) and it looked okay. That's also why I'm checking with someone independent first to make sure we're not nitpicky.

As for plumbness of the walls the second spirit level picture shows the bubble.

Comment: Plumb is important, but "straight" or lack thereof is harder to work with. Your underlying wall might be very curved, and this tiler didn't have the skill to cheat to flat. Side thought: if you don't re-do, make sure your grout color is **very** close to your tile color.